# Webflux from Flux<List<Object> to Mono<List<Object>>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is there a way to achieve this in such way that if Flux is empty to obtain in the end a Mono.Empty?

My solution:

```
a = Flux<List<Object>>

a.reduce(new ArrayList<Object>(), (accumulated, current) -> {
   accumulated.addAll(current);
   return accumulated;
})
```

The problem with my solution is that if `List<Object<>>` is empty, I would get in the end a `Mono<emptyArrayList>` . And I would like to have `Mono.Empty` to be able to handle this event with `switchIfEmpty` method

Comment: Is `flatMap` insufficient?

Comment: more specific???

Comment: what about a simple filter in the end? `a.filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())`

Comment: yup. I ended up with this approach. Thanks